# How to name an argument inside a function with the input parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Let's say I want to import tickers from yahoo finance and want to create  a function for the same. How can I create it a way that I can name the variable of the said ticker within the function?

For example:

```
def function(x, y):
    x = pdr.get_data_yahoo(y, start, end)
    return x
```

Here I want to take `x` input as the name that the we want to assign to the variable and `y` as the ticker. Which would be in a 'AAPL' format.

For example:

```
function(aapl, 'AAPL')
```

Is there any way to achieve this so I can quickly import a historical data and assign it to a variable?

Comment: Why not remove `x` as parameter from `function` and call it like `aapl = function('AAPL')`?

Comment: Python variables don't work like that. Either `aapl = function('AAPL')` or, if you really need something dynamic, use a `dict` like `keyname = 'aapl'; d[keyname] = function('AAPL')`.

Comment: What if i wanted to not just do aapl ? i want to take any ticker as an input. and change the name of the variable accordingly.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: so that means i would have to manualy create dicts for several tickers and that is the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function below will return what you want without local variable x:

```
def function(y):
    return pdr.get_data_yahoo(y, start, end)
```

If you want to create a variable in local scope with a given name it is generally not possible. Function locals() returns local scope as dict, but updates are implementation dependent, you will not create local variable by modifying this dict, so avoid the approach. If you need key value assignment use dict like:

```
def function(x, y):
    d = {x: pdr.get_data_yahoo(y, start, end)} # or just return d
    return d
```

Comment: This works as i would just have to do this and then assign the function to a variable outside the function-
ie -
     aapl = function(y)